# ¿Cómo agregar iconos diferentes a cada item del menú con Recyclerview?

Tags: recyclerview, menú

Estoy tratando de construir un menú vertical y expandible, he agregado a mi menu drawer un recyclerview, el menú tiene tres categorías; las categorías lleban un icono que me gustaría saber cómo hago para que sea un icono diferente en cada categoría.

Para el caso de las subCategorias tambien muestra solo la etiqueta del submenu, ¿Cómo puedo poner una imagen también aquí en cada item y que cada una sea diferente? Lo que no quiero es que el ícono se repita en todos los items. por favor, su ayuda, a continuación dejo los códigos:

list_categoria.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#dfa3a3">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_genre_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_electric_guitar" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_genre_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:textColor="#02400b"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Genre" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_genre_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ViewHolder
MenuCategoriaViewHolder

```
 public class MenuCategoriaViewHolder extends GroupViewHolder {

    private TextView genreTitle;

    public MenuCategoriaViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        genreTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_genre_name);
    }

    public void setGenreName(String name){
        genreTitle.setText(name);
    }

}
```

Para los sub_menu:
list_subcategoria.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_item_menu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_artist_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Artist Name" />
</FrameLayout>
```

ViewHolder
ItemMenuViewHolder

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

    private TextView artistName;

    public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artistName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_name);
    }

    public void setArtistName(String name){
        artistName.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Modelos:

MenuCategoria.java

```
public class MenuCategoria extends ExpandableGroup {
    public MenuCategoria(String title, List items) {
        super(title, items);
    }
}
```

ItemMenu.java

```
public class ItemMenu {
private String name;
private int imageId;

public ItemMenu(String name, int imageid) {
    this.name = name;
    this.imageId = imageid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getImageId() {
    return imageId;
}

public void setImageid(int imageid) {
    this.imageId = imageid;
}
```

}

Adaptador:
MenuAdapter.java

```
  public class MenuAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder> {

public MenuAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
    super(groups);
}

@Override
public MenuCategoriaViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_categoria, parent, false);
    return new MenuCategoriaViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);
    return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
    ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

    holder.setArtistName(itemMenu.getName());
    holder.setArtistImage(itemMenu.getImageId());
}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MenuCategoriaViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
    holder.setGenreName(group.getTitle());
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

//variables recyclerview
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
private List<MenuCategoria> menuCategorias;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //RecyclerView en el navigationDrawer
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    getGenres();
    mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(menuCategorias);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}

public void getGenres() {

    menuCategorias = new ArrayList<>(3);

    List<ItemMenu> itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(5);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Portal",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Biblioteca",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("EduVirtual",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Directorio",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Preguntas",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Portal", itemMenus));

    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(2);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Siga",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Apoyo a la Presencialidad",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Virtualidad",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Plataformas", itemMenus));

    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(7);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Facebook",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Twitter",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Linkedin",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Flicker",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Youtube",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Google +",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Instagram",R.drawable.ic_electric_guitar));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Redes Sociales", itemMenus));


}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También me pueden ayudar si me orientan a cómo hacerlo desde cero, en éste caso he tomado la plantilla de un navigationDrawer, elimine el menú y coloque el expandable recyclerView, lo que busco es que este menú sea expandible y que cada item vaya acompañado de un ícono diferente. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que necesitas hacer es en tu clase **ItemMenu** agregar una propiedad que haga referencia a una imagen/icono puedes ponerla como **String** si es una url de una imagen en internet por ejemplo, o puede ser **int** si es un recurso local ejemplo: ***R.drawable.mi_icono*** luego en **ItemMenuViewHolder** insertas el valor de tu objeto **ItemMenu**.

Puedes apoyarte con esta librería: [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).

Entonces tu código quedaría así:

ItemMenu.java

```
public class ItemMenu {
    private String name, imageUrl;

    public ItemMenu(String name, String imageUrl) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void ImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

}
```

ViewHolder ItemMenuViewHolder

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

    private TextView artistName;
    private  ImageView artistImage

    public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        artistName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_name);
        artistImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_artist_image);

    }

    public void setArtistName(String name){
        artistName.setText(name);
    }

    public void setArtistName(String image){
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(image)
            .into(artistImage);
    }

}
```

Adaptador: MenuAdapter.java

```
  public class MenuAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder> {

    public MenuAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuCategoriaViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_categoria, parent, false);
        return new MenuCategoriaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);
        return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

        holder.setArtistName(itemMenu.getName());
        holder.setArtistImage(itemMenu.getImageUrl());    
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MenuCategoriaViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        holder.setGenreName(group.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias, es un recurso local en la carpeta drawable, agregue la etiqueta ImagenView en list_subcategoria.xml; realice el cambio de String por int; ¿que mas debería cambiar para que carguen las imágenes?; al método que agregaste setArtistName le cambié de nombre por setArtistImage(int image), allí en el parametro context muestra error y pide crear una variable local. gracias.

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta con los cambios aunque aun no me muestra los iconos.

Comment: Que error te muestra exactamente ?

Comment: Ya lo he logrado, se que tu ayuda es correcta lo que ocurre es que aun me falta mucha experiencia en esto y algunas veces no sé aplicar las soluciones que me dan, te agradezco.

Comment: Hola @Manuel me puedes ayudar con esta otra pregunta por favor?  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110234/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-fragmentos-de-acuerdo-a-los-items-recyclerview/110366#110366