# Cómo cambiar fragmentos de acuerdo a los items RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, fragment, transacciones

A partir de una plantilla `NavigationDrawer` de Android Studio he reemplazado el menú por un RecyclerView Expandible, ahora quisiera agregar evento `OnClick` para poder cambiar los fragmentos en el contenido principal. Ya tengo un menú elaborado; no sé donde agregar las transacciones para cada cambio de fragment. en la web no he encontrado un ejemplo parecido, en algunos casos lo hacen con un toast.
Tengo por ejemplo dos fragmentos nombrados: `Biblioteca` y `Evu`.
A continuación el código de mi proyecto.

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {

private View.OnClickListener listener;

    public MenuAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

    @Override
    public MenuCategoriaViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_categoria, parent, false);
        return new MenuCategoriaViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);

        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

        holder.setItemName(itemMenu.getItemName());
        holder.setIcono(itemMenu.getImagenId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MenuCategoriaViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
        holder.setCategoriaName(group.getTitle());
    }

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (listener!=null){
        listener.onClick(view);
    }
    }
}
```

En el `MainActivity` es donde se carga el `MenuRecyclerView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//variables recyclerview
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
private List<MenuCategoria> menuCategorias;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    //RecyclerView en el navigationDrawer
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    getCateg();
    mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(menuCategorias);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

}

public void getCateg() {

    menuCategorias = new ArrayList<>(1);

    List<ItemMenu> itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(5);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Home",R.mipmap.home)); // comentarié los demás submenus para ensayar solo con uno
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Biblioteca",R.mipmap.biblioteca));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("EduVirtual",R.mipmap.eduvirtual));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Directorio",R.mipmap.directorio));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Preguntas",R.mipmap.preguntasf));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Portal", itemMenus));

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

ViewHolder

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder {

private TextView itemName;
private ImageView icono;

public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
    icono = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scate_icon);
}

public void setItemName(String name){
    itemName.setText(name);
}

public void setIcono(int idResource){
    icono.setImageResource(idResource);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La respuesta que voy a dar es casi la misma que di en esta **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/104681/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-clickeables-2-o-m%C3%A1s-elementos-en-una-cardview)**, con la diferencia de que en esta, la clase `ViewHolder` se declara fuera del adaptador y por eso hay que pasarle como parametro en su constructor la interfaz que se crea en el adaptador para poder capturar los eventos onClick que se generen al precionar los items del `RecyclerView`.

Para lograr lo que quieres tienes que:

- Crear una interfaz que comunique el adaptador con la actividad.
- Pasar la interfaz a la clase ViewHolder.
- Implementar la interfaz `OnClickListener` en la clase ViewHolder.
- Apuntar los eventos onClick de los componentes (elementos) de la clase ViewHolder al método `onClick()` de la interfaz OnClickListener.
- Por ultimo llamas el método `setOnClickListener()` que declaraste en el adaptador.

#### MenuAdapter

```
public class MenuAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder> {

    // Creas la interfaz que implementaras en la actividad
    public interface EventoOnItemClick {
        public void onItemClick(int posicion);
    }

    EventoOnItemClick listener;

    ...

    @Override
    public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);

        // view.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Creas y retornas el ViewHolder que contiene los componentes (vistas)
        // y le pasas como parametro la vista inflada y la interfaz.
        return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view, listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
        ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

        holder.setItemName(itemMenu.getItemName());
        holder.setIcono(itemMenu.getImagenId());
        holder.setPosicion(childIndex);
    }

    public void setOnClickListener(EventoOnItemClick listener){
        this.listener=listener;
    }

    ...

    /*@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (listener!=null){
            listener.onClick(view);
        }
    }*/
}
```

#### ItemMenuViewHolder

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    ...

    EventoOnItemClick listener; // Recibe la interfaz enviada desde el adaptador
    int posicion; // Recibe la posicion enviada desde le adaptador

    public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView, EventoOnItemClick listener) {
        super(itemView);

        ...

        // Apuntas el evento onClick del item al metodo onClick 
        // de la interfaz OnClickListener. 
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // Inicializas el listener
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    ...

    public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
        this.posicion = posicion; // Inicializa la posicion
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        listener.onItemClick(posicion);
    }

}
```

#### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ...

        //RecyclerView en el navigationDrawer
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        getCateg();
        mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(menuCategorias);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new MenuAdapter.EventoOnItemClick() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int posicion) {

                switch (posicion) {

                    case 1:
                        // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento cuando se precione
                        // el primer item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento cuando se precione
                        // el segundo item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento cuando se precione
                        // el tercer item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                        break;
                }

            }
        });

        ...

    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: tengo problemas para hacer los pasos que me dices en la respuesta, no he hecho antes una interfaz, si es posiblle ayudame en el **[proyecto](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp)** gracias

Comment: He agregado una nueva pregunta dandole continuidad a esta pregunta, me ayudas por favor:  **[PREGUNTA](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/110519/34903)**

Comment: Ya modifique tu proyecto, le estoy haciendo push ahora. Mi respuesta tiene unos cuantos errores, ya la edito.

Comment: gracias estoy atento

Comment: @Davis hoy empecé a usar GitHub me avisas como puedo ver lo que has modificado por favor.

Comment: @Alfredo entra a tu **Github** y acepta el **Pull requests** que envié. Lo encontraras en la pestaña con el mismo nombre, el nombre del pull requests que envié es: **Se agrego el evento onClickListener a los items del RecyclerView**. Puedes entrar directamente haciendo click **[aquí](https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp/pulls)**

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67312/discussion-between-alfredo-and-david).