# Error Cannot resolve symbol 'EventoOnItemClick'

Tags: android-fragment, recyclerview, onclicklistener

estoy tratando de poner eventos OnClickListener a los items de un recyclerview, ya en la anterior **[pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110234/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-fragmentos-de-acuerdo-a-los-items-recyclerview/110463#110463)** me han orientado con estos **[pasos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/110463/34903)**, sin embargo creo que algo no va bien en la creación de la interfaz ya que me está dando dos errores en el MainActivity. a continuación los códigos, gracias por la ayuda:

MenuAdapter

```
public class MenuAdapter extends 
ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder>{

EventoOnItemClick listener;

public MenuAdapter(List<? extends ExpandableGroup> groups) {
        super(groups);
    }

@Override
public MenuCategoriaViewHolder onCreateGroupViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_categoria, parent, false);
    return new MenuCategoriaViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public ItemMenuViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int 
viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.list_subcategoria, parent, false);
        //view.setOnClickListener(this);
    return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view, listener);
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(ItemMenuViewHolder holder, int flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group, int childIndex) {
    ItemMenu itemMenu = (ItemMenu) group.getItems().get(childIndex);

    holder.setItemName(itemMenu.getItemName());
    holder.setIcono(itemMenu.getImagenId());
    holder.setPosicion(childIndex);
}

public void setOnClickListener(EventoOnItemClick listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}

@Override
public void onBindGroupViewHolder(MenuCategoriaViewHolder holder, int 
flatPosition, ExpandableGroup group) {
    holder.setCategoriaName(group.getTitle());
}
```

}

ItemMenuViewHolder

```
public class ItemMenuViewHolder extends ChildViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener{

EventoOnItemClick listener; // Recibe la interfaz enviada desde el adaptador
int posicion; // Recibe la posicion enviada desde le adaptador


private TextView itemName;
private ImageView icono;

public ItemMenuViewHolder(View itemView, EventoOnItemClick listener) {
    super(itemView);
    itemName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_name);
    icono = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_scate_icon);

    // Apuntas el evento onClick del item al metodo onClick
    // de la interfaz OnClickListener.
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Inicializas el listener
    this.listener = this.listener;
}

public void setItemName(String name){
    itemName.setText(name);
}

public void setIcono(int idResource){
    icono.setImageResource(idResource);
}

public void setPosicion(int posicion) {
    this.posicion = posicion; // Inicializa la posicion
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    listener.onItemClick(posicion);
}
```

}

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements Fragment_biblioteca.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

//variables recyclerview
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private MenuAdapter mAdapter;
private List<MenuCategoria> menuCategorias;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    final Fragment biblioteca = new Fragment_biblioteca();

    //RecyclerView en el navigationDrawer
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    getCateg();
    mAdapter = new MenuAdapter(menuCategorias);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new 
    LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this));
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new MenuAdapter.EventoOnItemClick() {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int posicion) {

            switch (posicion) {

                case 1:
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main, biblioteca).commit();
                    // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento 
                     cuando se precione
                    // el primer item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                    break;

                case 2:
                    // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento 
                    cuando se precione
                    // el segundo item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                    break;

                case 3:
                    // Aqui colocas el codigo para lanzar el fragmento 
                    cuando se precione
                    // el tercer item del ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter
                    break;
            }
        }
    });


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

public void getCateg() {

    menuCategorias = new ArrayList<>(1);

    List<ItemMenu> itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(5);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Home",R.mipmap.home)); // comentarié los 
    demás submenus para ensayar solo con uno
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Biblioteca",R.mipmap.biblioteca));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("EduVirtual",R.mipmap.eduvirtual));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Directorio",R.mipmap.directorio));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Preguntas",R.mipmap.preguntasf));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Portal", itemMenus));
    /*
    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(2);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Siga"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Apoyo a la Presencialidad"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Virtualidad"));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Plataformas", itemMenus));

    itemMenus = new ArrayList<>(7);
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Facebook"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Twitter"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Linkedin"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Flicker"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Youtube"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Google +"));
    itemMenus.add(new ItemMenu("Instagram"));
    menuCategorias.add(new MenuCategoria("Redes Sociales", itemMenus));
    */
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Los errores que me muestra en Code Analysis son:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La interfaz: EventoOnItemClick

```
public interface EventoOnItemClick {
   public void onItemClick(int posicion);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega la definición de la interfaz dentro de la clase  `MenuAdapter` :

```
    public class MenuAdapter extends 
ExpandableRecyclerViewAdapter<MenuCategoriaViewHolder, ItemMenuViewHolder>{

        //Definición de interfaz.
        public interface EventoOnItemClick {
            public void onItemClick(int posicion);
        }

        EventoOnItemClick listener;

        ...
        ...
```

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, al agregar esta definición me genera error en la linea return new ItemMenuViewHolder(view, listener); Cast 2dn parameter to 'pakage... EventoOnItemClick' . :(

Comment: he subido el proyecto a GitHub podrías por favor ayudarme.

Comment: dame el url y llegando a casa lo reviso!

Comment: Gracias ya eso lo resolvi, pero ahora tengo una nueva pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/111006/34903 y mi repositorio esta en https://github.com/ivanlobeloc/UniagustApp